# How to add to first array element?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, datatable

I have a set of result from sql query which I fill in a datatable:

```
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Then I converted the dt to an array:

```
string[][] mergeBlockData = 
        dt.Rows
        .OfType<DataRow>().Select(r => dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
        .Select(c => r[c.ColumnName].ToString())
        .ToArray())
        .ToArray();
```

I also want to add the column name in the first array element. How?

This is the mergeBlockData when hardcoded

```
 string[][] mergeBlockData = new string[][] {
  new string[] { "connection_number", "connection_duration", "fee" },
  new string[] { "7777", "3:15", "€ 10.0" },
  new string[] { "6666", "23:15", "€ 20.0" },
  new string[] { "5555", "13:15", "€ 30.0" },
  new string[] { "8888", "83:15", "€ 40.0" } };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT (after requirements change):**

Try this:

```
string[][] mergeBlockData = 
     new List<string[]>{ dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(dc => dc.ColumnName).ToArray() }.Concat(
     dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
         .Select(
        r => dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
            .Select(c => r[c.ColumnName].ToString()).ToArray()
         )
     )
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: How come the datatable has any issue, i just fill the dt using adapter.Fill(). But the columns has empty value here and there.

Comment: @lyas: What are column names in `dt` object?

Comment: proj_12, proj_obj_12, proj_remarks_12, proj_impak_12

Comment: I think i'm looking at the wrong place, when i use the stringRepresentation alone, it's ok.. the result is as expected, but when i use with LiveDocx lib (for creating pdf) then the problem occurs.

Comment: @lyas: please review your question and update it according to your real case

Comment: I think i know the problem, the LiveDocX lib requires the first element to be the column name.. so I've edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

The error `"A column named ' ' already belongs to this DataTable."` comes from the DataTable creation, not from the string representation creation.

Make sure that your DataTable is built only once with no duplicates in the columns name.

As to properly create your string representation, you can do it with a loop over your Rows:

string[][] stringRepresentation = new string[dt.Rows.Count][];

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < dt.Rows.Count ; ++i)
 stringRepresentation[i] = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```